# System language; does it limit app availability in the built-in Ubuntu app program?

Tags: appmenu, language-support, system-language

My system language is Danish.
I'm new to Linux.

I don't seem to have so many possible app choices. But the ones I have installed so far all have menus in Danish.

Am I limiting my possibilities because of my language setting?
If yes: how could I solve this and keep the language setting. (I don't need the Danish support from the apps.)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, the selected display language does not affect which applications that are available.

Indeed, everything isn't translated to Danish (no language is 100% translated), and untranslated strings will be shown in English.

For guidance on how to change it, please [look here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html).